# Box API v2 uploading multiple files per single request is limited to 20

Tags: box-api

I'm using Box API v2.0. When I try to upload more than 20 files per single request, only first 20 files are uploaded on server.

I receive such response:

```
{ 
  "total_count": 20,
  "entries": [{
    "type": "file",
    "id": "2365556604",
    ...
  }, ... ]
}
```

I can't find any mention about such limit in documentation, moreover I can upload any number of files using API v1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just looked into this, and it is indeed a bug with the v2 API. We are working on resolving it, and I will update here when it has been fixed.

Comment: I just came across the same issue. Is there any timeline on when this would be fixed?